# rails db:seed fails with `LoadError: cannot load such file -- JSON` despite `'json`' in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

## notes

- rails db:create and migrate both work, but I'm getting an error when trying to seed
- postgres db successfully writes new records on post from the react client
- running ruby 2.5.0 and rails 5.2.0 from alpine-based ruby image

## command

`docker-compose run api rails db:seed`

## response:

```
Starting full-circle_db_1 ... done
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- JSON
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
```

## Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'json', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'faker'
gem 'pry'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'faraday', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'stripe', '~> 1.57', '>= 1.57.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a `require 'JSON'` somewhere in your code?  It should be lower-case `json`.

Comment: holy shit. Nick, I would like to give you all the money in my wallet right now. Thanks so much.

Comment: Hah, that comment is plenty. Glad I could help.